# libphp*.so / php.conf がインストールされない

Tags: php

【環境】
mac 10.14.1(host)
Virtualbox6.0
vagrant 2.2.2
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

【現象】
https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/860ba080bf4c664cd8e9
を参考に複数のphp(php56/70/71)バージョンをインストールして、
module load php７１ で
php71を有効にしていますが、
ブラウザからphpファイルにアクセスすると php のソースがそのまま表示されます
※ほかの php バージョンでも同じ

php71 のインストール
yum-config-manager --enable remi
yum -y install php71

【原因】
/etc/httpd/modules に libphp*.so がない
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf がない

【質問】
どうすれば、 module と php.conf がインストールされて、
module load php* をするだけで php のバージョンを切り替えられる環境を構築できるでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします

--追記 > take88様
参照ページで実施したいのは、「URLで環境を切り替える」の手前までで、

> module load <モジュール名> で切り替える。単体で切り替えるだけの場合はこれで充分だろう。

とあるので、php-fpm を使わないでやる方法があるのだろうと認識しています

実際に「URLで環境を切り替える」のほうは参照ページの通りに、/etc/hosts 含めて設定をして url によって php のバージョンを切り替えられるのは確認しました

そこまで確認した上で、php-fpmを停止しremi.confを削除した状態で、質問のような現象となりつまづいている状況です

fpm を検証する前に、 module load の時点でも現象は同じだったので、はじめから libphp*.so や php.conf はインストールされなかったのではないかと推測しています

従って、この状態から libphp.so や php.conf を php の複数バージョンに対応した形でインストールするにはどうすればいいか、ご教示いただける方がいると大変ありがたいです

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 参考記事を読みますと PHP-FPMはCGIなのでApacheのModuleは不要だと思います。php.confも不要な気がします。httpdの設定が正しいか今一度確認したほうが良いかも。conf.d の下に余計な設定ファイルがあったりしませんか？ また名前ベースのバーチャルホストが有効になってるかが気になります。可能でしたら設定ファイルの内容を質問に追記してください。質問の編集は推奨されてますのでぜひどうぞ。

Comment: > Taichi Yanagiyaさん
ありがとうございます。すっかり遅くなってしまいましたが無事にPHPを動かすことができました
本当に助かりました！

Answer (score 1):

Apache モジュールは `php71-php` に含まれています。
php71-php をインストールしてみてください。